# Drop down stubs are not being hidden and disabled in IE

Tags: jquery

I am facing very serious problems with internet explorer..  I have been trying to hide some  stubs of drop down using jQuery. It worked fine in all the browsers except in internet explorer.  This was my code

```
 $('TABLE TBODY select').find("option[value='1']").hide();
```

I have posted this in our community , but i got responses saying that option hiding will not work in IE. Then later i changed the code to

```
 $('TABLE TBODY select').find("option[value='1']").prop('disabled',true);
```

It is working fine in IE8 but not in IE7. Please someone help me.

Comment: Why don't you just remove them? $('TABLE TBODY select').find("option[value='1']").detach();

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried it with [toggle()](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/).

```
$('TABLE TBODY select').find("option[value='1']").toggle();
```

I have been through this situation once long time ago. And I guess I resolved it by using toggle(). Hope that will work in your case as well.